# How to get my answer accepted.

Tags: support, moderators, accepted-answer

The question [Let $ \ n_1 , \ n_2 , \ n_3 , \ ............., \ n_k \ $ be positive numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488758/let-n-1-n-2-n-3-n-k-be-positive-numbers) was posted a week ago. I answered it on the same day, i.e., a week ago. There are no other answers. There is one comment, which doesn't seem to answer question.

Is there anything I can do about it? Can a moderator do something? How do I get a moderator to look at it?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is...

Comment: What do you want? What do you want somebody to do? What do you want to happen? You can post a comment under the question, asking the questioner whether he/she has any thoughts about your answer.

Comment: @qudit the title of the question changed somehow. I have fixed it.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson the title of the question changed somehow. I have fixed it.

Comment: If what you want to know is how to get your answer accepted, then that should be in the body of your question, not just in the title. But, anyway: it is entirely up to the person who posted the question as to whether or not to accept your or any answer. There is no way that you or anyone else can compel that person to accept an answer. You can leave a comment, as I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: What post, where?  And in any case, unfortunately, the same thing has happened to most answerers on the site.  There are users who ask questions, but don't accept an answer.  And there are some who accept answers only when they've been helpful.  Since you don't link to it here, I can't help you anymore than that.

Comment: @amWhy I tried to look up how to link to MSE post. I'm not an expert on links. But I couldn't find anything quickly. I guess I'll ask that as a question.

Comment: @amWhy The title of the post is "Let  $n_1, n_2, n_3, …, n_k$ be positive numbers."

Comment: Thank you, @StephenMeskin

Comment: @StephenMeskin : If you do care about getting your answer accepted, before answering you may take a look at the previous questions the questioner asked. Do not answer if you find they do not accept answers in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask them to accept it, but no one is going to force anyone to accept your answer.  Sometimes no answer is accepted even when there are multiple good answers.  Accepting answers is entirely up to the asker.